# PHP Project Deployment

Tags: php, svn, deployment, capistrano, phing

I would like to **deploy** our **php projects**, but I don't know how to go with our typical project.

Our project is based on our **CMS**. We customize the CMS with extensions(plugins) and **customized templates**. The CMS core and CMS extensions are in SVN. Customization means, that we do some changes in templates without commiting to SVN. If the SVN version changed, we can update the project to up-to-date version, but usually some conflicts will rise...

Is there an easy way to have an up-to-date CMS/extensions versions in customized projects? Is deploying with **Phing** or **Capistrano** the right way?

Please, give me some tips, pages etc. with simillar issues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you ever heard of branches? Or svn:externals for that matter? These will be able to solve part of your problem, while retaining a solid code repository containing your changes for specific clients. When creating a new project : create a copy of your CMS in a new branch or create a separate repository and import your CMS code using svn:externals (or use a vendor branch). When you have CMS updates you can merge these in the clients repo/branch as you see fit. We always use a different repo per client and 1 main repo for our CMS (and that seems quite logical to me).

Comment: Thanks. That's seems logical. But I am afraid of conflicts. I have to consider to make branches/externals. Ideally I would like to automatize merging. Thanks

Comment: With a vendor branch you can merge the client specific changes with your CMS changes easily. Of course there's no guarantee that there won't be any conflicts, but if you don't move files around or rename them and you don't have client-specific changes that are not backwards compatible, it should be a breeze to upgrade your CMS releases :p. And personally I'd rather spend my time resolving conflicts then to managing a zillion different unversioned projects (been there, done that, never again).

Comment: I totally understand :) Thanks - I am studying svn:externals :)

Answer (score 1):

I must note that your way of handling projects goes entirely against the way version control should be used. You should always be able to commit changes - else your versions aren't kept.

On your deploying question, I'd say investigate **rsync**. Phing is also an excellent solution.

Comment: We create new project "every week" from the CMS core and the customization takes 1 to 2 months. So we have a several projects and we can't commit projects into one repository... we need to show changes from repository to customized projects. Is it clear?

Comment: Maybe - the SVN is not suitable for this treatment... should we move on Git? Or make some other changes? I am open to accept any idea :)

Comment: wimvds has a good comment, in a nutshell it says how the company I work at handles this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a build system that we made with phing and we replaced our capistrano deployment system with it. We use Git exclusively and many of our projects use the same build procedures so we wanted a system that we could add to any project as a git submodule and start building/deploying right away. You're welcome to use it and fork it if you want to.

https://github.com/CodeMeme/Phingistrano

Answer (score 0):

Create a new repository for each project and use SVN externals to include the CMS core into your project repository. Not commiting code is a huge fail.